# Pandas: Define categorical dtype with categories in DataFrame constructor

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to initialize the dtypes of a DataFrame's columns to categorical types and specify each column's categories on its creation.

This way seems less efficient because I loop over `animals` twice:

```
col_name = pd.Categorical([a.name for a in animals], categories=['bird','cat','dog'])
col_food = pd.Categorical([a.food for a in animals], categories=['meat','veggies'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': col_name, 'Food': col_food})
```

This way seems more efficient because I loop over `animals` just once but how can I specify the categorical columns' categories?:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'Animal': a.name, 'Food': a.food} for a in animals], 
                  dtype={'Animal': ???, 'Food': ???})
```

I also want to avoid creating the DataFrame first, then converting the columns' types to categorical.

Something like:
`dtype={'Food': dtype('category', categories=['meat','veggies]), ...}`

Comment: What is `animals` ? another df?

Comment: maybe works `dtype={'Animal': "category", 'Food': "category"})`

Comment: @jezrael No, just a simple Python list of class objects

Comment: @jezrael Yes, this may work if you want it to infer the categories from the column values, but I want to specify the categories.

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible, but if it is some object, I cannot test it. Can you change your sample to working - add object `animal` for working for me and another answerers?

Answer (score 0):

since you don't put your animal class i use a easy one that have name and food attributes.

```
import pandas as pd

class Animal():
    def __init__(self, name, food):
        self.name = name
        self.food = food

cat = Animal('cat','meat')
bird = Animal('bird', 'veggies')
dog = Animal('dog','meat')

animals = [cat, dog, bird, bird, dog, cat, cat, cat, dog, dog]

df = pd.DataFrame([{'Animal': a.name, 'Food': a.food} for a in animals], dtype=(pd.Categorical))
print(df.Animal.cat.categories)
print(df.Food.cat.categories)
```

And the output is:

```
Index(['bird', 'cat', 'dog'], dtype='object')
Index(['meat', 'veggies'], dtype='object')
```

I hope this is what are you looking for.

Comment: In this solution, I can't specify the ordering of the categories though. Is there another way? :-)